# github default branch is main but not master

Tags: github

I created a new repo in GitHub.
I init the git `git init` locally and
`git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo_name.git`

then created and added few files locally `git add` then commit `git commit -m "commit msg"`
when I pushed it to my GitHub repo, it's creating a new branch `master` but not default, however, the default is the `main` branch [strange, never saw this branch before].

Now I have `main (default)` and `master` branches which are unexpected.

And, also didn't let me merge the pushed file.

How do I simply have master branch as default and ignore main branch? if not what's the way to let create pull request on main and merge the files?

Comment: You can pick whatever default branch you like: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/changing-the-default-branch

Comment: Thanks.
I also end up making master as the default branch.

Comment: FYI: The change from `master` to `main` is very deliberate, and part of a broader effort to remove the term “master” from software. I’d consider maintaining the `main` branch. GitHub is offering tools to aid in this migration. You can read more on [GitHub’s announcement](https://github.com/github/renaming/) from last year.

Comment: Thank @JeremyCaney, 
Interesting read, Github is actually updating `master` as `main` to avoid confusion of the master-slave concept. Coming in the future there will be no `master` branch. And they already updated in Github.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the master as the default branch.

[image]

Simple as that.